# Merge clipboards

Tags: clipboard

Is there any simple script that can merge and synchronize all clipboards (especially, X-selection-paste and copy-paste)? I have found numerous solution, but all of them are ended with installing a full software (like parcellite or autocutsel)

Comment: Could you add an example please ?

Comment: I have found some solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/68170/how-can-i-merge-the-gnome-clipboard-and-the-x-selection)